# Jquery to Prototype conversion

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I'm trying to convert this

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j('.products-grid li.item').hover(function(){ 
  j(".products-grid li.item").not(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(300, .8); 
},function(){ 
  j(".products-grid li.item").stop(true,true).fadeTo(300, 1);  
});
```

to prototype but cannot find an equivalent .not. 
Anyone give me some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) to get an [`Array`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/) of elements. That means you can use [`Array.without`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/prototype/without/).

---

Example:
If `this` is the element (as in your above code) then use:

```
$$(".products-grid li.item").without(this)
```

Comment: How can i use array.without, with the jquery its just targeting all li's with class item except the currently hovered one. I'm a prototype novice

Comment: Please see the updated example.

Comment: How do you do a newline in comments?
So I'm tring this

`$$(".products-grid li.item").observe('h', function(e) {
var this = Event.element(e);
new Effect.Opacity(".products-grid li.item", {duration:0.5, from:1.0, to: 0.5}).without(this);
});`

BUt its not even firing

Comment: It's not firing because there is no `'h'` event. Since comments cannot do newlines it might be better to edit your question directly with the code in progress.